# Do not see created file in the host directory mounted by hostPath

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster of 1 master & 1 worker. I deployed 1 nodejs application and mounted a directory `/home/user_name/data` using `hostPath` volume type to the pod. The type I set to `Directory` for the volume.

The nodejs application is working perfectly and writing data to and returning the saved data without any error.

Initially, I also tested by deleting the `data` folder and trying to apply the deployment and I received error as the volume type is `Directory`. So it looks the mount is correctly pointing to the directory in the worker node. But when I am trying to see the file which should be created by the nodejs app, I do not see any file in the host directory.

I also checked if the pod is running on worker node and it's running on worker node only.

Mu understanding about `hostPath` volume type is that it's similar to `bindMount` volume type of docker.

**I have not idea why I cannot see the file which the nodejs app is creating and working perfectly. Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `hostPath` directories for routine application storage; you can't guarantee that the pod will always be on the same node, or that there won't be multiple pods from the same deployment running in the same place.  Choose one of the other volume types.

Comment: please add volumes & volumeMounts part of your yaml file to have more clarity

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes you are right. Axtually I was trying to clarify my understanding on hostPath as we use small time caches in our application so I was thinking if we can user `hostPath`.

Comment: Probably the only time you should use `hostPath` is if you're running something like a log collector as a DaemonSet, where the pod will run on every node, and you know the same filesystem path will exist on every node with interesting content.  It isn't something you should use normally.